# Queue Automata can simulate any Pushdown Automata?

Tags: queue, theory, state-machine, pushdown-automaton

I'm working on a theory assignment, and this question really got me thinking. The question reads: Show that any push-down automata can be simulated by a queue automata. Now, Initially I thought this would be straightforward, but then I thought about L = {WW^R | W = {a, b}*} (W^R is the reverse of W) This is simple to create in the general form of a push-down automaton, but I cant think of any way to do it in the general form of a queue automaton. I don't think there is a (finite) general case we can design for this. I might be over thinking it too, as I might just misunderstand what simulated means. Anyway, I'm more likely to be wrong than the question is, but how does it work for the case I mentioned?

Thanks for any help you provide!

Comment: Belongs to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There's a trick to do this pretty simply:

1) Show that a queue [can simulate a full Turing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_automaton#Turing_completeness). In short, put the Turing tape on the queue, wrapped around with special markers for the ends of the tape as well as the read head. (If it's not clear from there, take a look at the wiki link or leave a comment)

2) Note that a Turing machine is strictly more powerful than a PDA, so it must be able to simulate a PDA.